# convert image path to http url

Tags: c#, asp.net

a third party API doesn't consider image path and display nothing in image,,instead a http URL works.

I am creating a webservice and 
My requirement is to

Convert an image path to a http url..

for example instead of http://office.microsoft.com/global/images/mypic.jpg

i want

http://office.microsoft.com/global/images/default.aspx?assetid=ZA103873861033

thanks people

Comment: ehmm does both look like URLs to me? What again is the question or the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image path is already an HTTP URL.  (as long as it has a domain name)

You don't need to do anything.

Comment: well i might have put up wrongly..the 3rd party api is able to read and dsipaly the url with no image extensionn to it....but if i give soemthing.jpg it wont read...i wanted to convert the .jpg extension to html or .aspx , i guess we can do it by embedding it inside img src tag of html...but how to do it..how do i pass value from my appcode.cs file to a aspx page and then form the tag dynamically

Comment: @sajad: Then something is very wrong with the API.  There is no sane reason for such a limitation.  You should contact the vendor and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: well may be something is wrong with API..but it does work when i give url..:).i have to adapt to api and try out..nywys thnks

Comment: @sajad: Is the API asking for an image or an HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

See both the paths u are showing  are Pure URLs
you dont need any processing..

And as i checked the link you gave above it looks like the Former URL makes the office.microsoft.com to create an image of the url itself and return and the latter one is fetching the resource and returning the image.

So in latter case also you need to know the assetid of the images that you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need a non-`.jpg` URL, you should make an ASHX handler which takes a filename on the querystring and calls `Response.TransmitFile` to forward a filename to the client.

You'll also to validate that the path in the querystring doesn't contain slashes, or you'll create a security hole.